# Splitting a string based on multiple delimeters using split() function in python by ignoring certain special characters present in the string

Tags: python, regex, string, list, split

Not getting desired result while splitting a string based on multiple delimiters and based on specific conditions.

I tried executing below code:

```
import re
text = r'ced"|"ms|n"|4|98'
finallist = re.split('\"\|\"|\"\||\|', text)
```

Here i'm trying to split string based on 3 delimiters by joining all using OR (|). First delimiter is by using "|" , another is "| and then using |

finallist looks like this:

```
finallist=['ced', 'ms','n', '4', '98']
```

However I don't wish the function to split at ms|n present in the string. As the pipe symbol is present inside the letters enclosed within double quotes i.e in this case "ms|n" so I don't want the function to match pipe symbol for this case.

And I'm expecting the finallist to look like this:

```
finallist=['ced', 'ms|n', '4', '98']
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this by changing the logic in the split function? Please let me know.

Comment: What is the rule for not matching `|` in `ms|n`? Is it a hardcoded value, or do you mean a pipe in between letters should not be matches? And it [splits at the final `|`](https://regex101.com/r/kmrevS/1).

Comment: Yes, pipe in between letters enclosed in a double quotes should not be matched. As in this case, ms|n is enclosed in double quotes as "ms|n" , so it shouldn't be matched.

Comment: Try `\"?\|(?!(?<=[A-Za-z]\|)(?=[a-zA-Z]))\"?`

Comment: I have tried with the one you mentioned. Now, I'm getting entire string value into the list as a single value, like this: ['ced"|"ms|n"|4|98']
It is not splitting the string.

Comment: Are you sure you tried *my* suggestion? See https://ideone.com/42jnU4 (see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kmrevS/2))

Comment: Hey sorry, my bad. Yes it did work. If I make small change in the string just by adding backslash Infront of pipe such as , text = r'ced"|"ms\|n"|4|98'  then the function is giving result as ['ced', 'ms\\', 'n', '4', '98']. Is there a way by which I can retain the exact value and get output as ['ced', 'ms\|n', '4', '98']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
"?\|(?!(?:(?<=[A-Za-z]\|)|(?<=[A-Za-z]\\\|))(?=[a-zA-Z]))"?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kmrevS/3). *Details*:

- `"?` - an optional `"` char
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `(?!(?:(?<=[A-Za-z]\|)|(?<=[A-Za-z]\\\|))(?=[a-zA-Z]))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is an ASCII letter immediately after the `|` char AND either an ASCII letter before the `|` char or an ASCII letter + `\` right before the `|` char
- `"?` - an optional `"` char

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/42jnU4):

```py
import re
text = r'ced"|"ms|n"|4|98'
pattern = r'"?\|(?!(?:(?<=[A-Za-z]\|)|(?<=[A-Za-z]\\\|))(?=[a-zA-Z]))"?'
print( re.split(pattern, text) )
# => ['ced', 'ms|n', '4', '98']
text = r'ced"|"ms\|n"|4|98'
print( re.split(pattern, text) )
# => ['ced', 'ms\\|n', '4', '98']
```

Comment: Hey, just checked that if I use this regex pattern on this string,
 text = r'2|nlac|esf|95768'  then it's not matching the pipe present in between c & e. output for this is coming as ['2', 'nlac|esf', '95768']. previously I said that I don't want to match the pipe if it's present in between letters enclosed in double quotes only. However as in this case, it's not enclose in double quote, I'm expecting the output to be  ['2', 'nlac', 'esf', '95768']. Could you pls let me know how this functionality can also be added to the above existing pattern mention by you.

Comment: @user16240226 There is a problem here since `ms|n` is not inside quotes. Look, in the first string, `"|"` - `|` is inside quotes and the next `"` is not paired. So, it is not a valid requirement. Please precise.

Comment: My requirement is there are 2 types of strings, on which I want to use a regex to get the desired output. if text = r'2|dgx|3|abc' and I use the above regex which was provided by you then I'm getting desired output only such as ['2', 'dgx', '3', 'ksfh']. However if the string is  text = r'2|dgx|abc|3'  then I'm getting output as ['2', 'dgx|abc', '3']. But I'm expecting output to be of ['2', 'dgx', 'abc', '3']. Is that possible to achieve?

Comment: By editing/modifying this same regex "?\|(?!(?:(?<=[A-Za-z]\|)|(?<=[A-Za-z]\\\|))(?=[a-zA-Z]))"? mentioned by you, can I achieve the above desired result?